# Why this sequence of R.V converge in distribution, but doesnt in probability

Tags: probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Why this sequence of R.V converge in distribution, but doesnt in probability?

Probability space $([0,1],B,m)$. ($B$ consists of all Borel sets of $[0,1]$, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.)

Let $X_{2n}(ω)=ω$, $X_{2n−1}(ω)=1−ω$

My intuiton says that I have to show that $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n−1}$ have the same distribution, which is an Uniform distribution. And after this, showing that they converge in distribution, which is obvious.

**But How can I show this?**

**And also**, how can I Show that $X_{n}$ does not converge in probability.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the convergence in distribution part. To show they have a uniform distribution, calculate the CDF. For instance, for $x\in (0,1),$ $P(X_0\le x) = P(\omega < x) = m(\{\omega :\omega <x\})=m((0,x)) = x,$ and you can compute similarly for $1-\omega.$

To show that it doesn't converge in probability, observe that the sequence oscillates between $\omega$ and $1-\omega.$ The distance between the two is $1-2\omega.$  Thus for $m$ even and $n$ odd, $P(|X_n-X_m|>\epsilon) =P(|1-2\omega|>\epsilon)>0.$ Thus $X_n$ is not Cauchy in probability and therefore not convergent in probabillity.

Comment: This would be the case that Exist the $F_{X}(x)$ but doesnt exist the $f_{X}(x)$. Many thanks by the way!!

Comment: @Laura No, the PDF exists. It is a uniform distribution

Comment: Yes yes , of course! Its $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y(\omega)=\omega$ and $Z(\omega)=1-\omega$. Then $X_{2n}\to Y$ in probability and  $X_{2n-1}\to Z$ in probability. If $X_n$ converges in probability then we must have $Y=Z$ almost surely which is false since $P(Y=Z)=0$.